# prove that if $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is cyclic, $n=2,4 $~or~$ p^k, 2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime number.

Tags: number-theory

prove that if $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is cyclic, $n=2,4$ or $p^k$, $2p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime number.

I thought of looking at two cases: $n = \Pi p_i^{k_i}$, $n = \Pi 2 p_i^{k_i}$  with $p_i \neq p_j$ if $i \neq j$ and check why these fail to be cyclic.

We see obviously that for both cases $\phi(n) = \Pi (p^{k_i} - p^{k_i - 1})$. this number is even as well because the $p_i$ are odd. Further than this i haven't come.

Any tips and tricks? Am i going to the right direction or is there a better trick in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $m,n$ be coprime positive integers. Then the Chinese Remainder Theorem says $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

This implies that $\left(\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times} \cong \left(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times} \times \left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}$ so in particular can't be cyclic  unless both of these components are cyclic and the orders are again coprime. This should reduce you to the case of prime powers or twice prime powers.

For powers of two, note that $(8k+a)^2 \equiv 1 \mod{8}$ whenever $a$ is odd and use this to construct an argument to why $\mathbb{Z}/2^l\mathbb{Z}$ has no primitive root for $l>2$.

Comment: can't the right hand side be cyclic if the groups have a generator with the same order?

Comment: No -  consider $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I've edited my statement slightly, but if you take $m,n$ to be powers of distinct odd primes then the orders of these groups can't be coprime (they are both divisible by 2) so the product can't be again cyclic in this case.

Comment: hmmmm, i can see that you can even say $n^2 = 1mod (8)$ if $n$ is odd. And it is clear that n has order $2$ but it should be $4$ to be cyclic in the case of 8. but what can  say about 1 mod 16, 1 mod 32 etc. because n^2 is not alway equal to 1 mod 16 and 1 mod 32 as well.

Comment: Show that if $a \mod{2^k}$ is a generator for $k>2$ then $a \mod{8}$ is a generator for $(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ which creates a contradiction. This is why any higher power of 2 cannot have a cyclic unit group since it fails at 8 so must fail for anything larger than 8.

Comment: This statement is the same as saying that $a^{2^k} = 1 \mod{2^{k+2}}$ for $k>1$ which is a contradiction as the unit group has order $2^{k+1}$, but I think its simpler to use the method I gave above.

Comment: thanks man i get it now :)